# Arduino Exception(9)

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm beginer with ESP8266 and getting Exception(9) every 1:30 min and can't figure out why;
After some testing i figure out that code below is the problem, but don't know why

```
struct Schedule
  {
    int temperatureMin;
    int temperatureMax;
    bool manual;
    const char* startTime;
    int id;
    int systemId;
    const char* stopTime;
  };

Schedule GetScheduleBySystem(int systemId)
    {
      Schedule sch;
      http.begin(api+"/systems/"+systemId+"/schedule",fingerPrint); //Specify the URL
      int httpCode = http.GET();             
        if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code

          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.println(httpCode);

          const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(7) + 238;
          DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(capacity);

          JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload);

          sch.startTime = root["start"]; // "2019-12-02T21:51:00"
          sch.temperatureMin = root["temperatureMin"]; // 22
          sch.temperatureMax = root["temperatureMax"]; // 32
          sch.manual = root["manual"]; // true
          sch.id = root["id"];
          sch.stopTime = root["stop"];
          sch.systemId = root["systemId"];
        }
        else 
        {
          Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
        }
        http.end(); //Free the resources
        return sch;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a while found that problem comes from this line of code 'http.getString()'.
I got rid of this exception by downgrading the ESP8266 software version  from 2.6.3 to 2.5.2.